# UTC Timestamp to normal timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I was trying the following code:

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00",
                                       "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"))
```

It was returning the error:

`ValueError: time data '2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'`

Comment: `Doesn't match` what is the output you want? We need details in your question in order to answer

Comment: you have space before `%z` but parsed time doesn't have it

Comment: I was trying the following code 
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00" ,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")) 

It was returning  the error 
ValueError: time data '2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'

Comment: please give the correct format for converting 2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00

Comment: It's always helpful to include the stack trace or error message you're seeing. Even better, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run directly.

Comment: remove space between `%S` and `%z` -  `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z`

Comment: removed space returns the following error removed 
        ValueError: time data '2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: Please **EDIT** your post and keep important info out of the comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not very familiar with the [datetime directives](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime), I will suggest you to use [`dateutil.parser`](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) instead. For example:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> s = '2016-10-17 02:35:01+00:00'
>>> my_date = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
>>> my_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 17, 2, 35, 1, tzinfo=tzutc())
```